# How to use fb connect in Android app?

Tags: android, facebook

```
public class FacebookConnect extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("");
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*
         * Get existing access_token if any
         */
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        /*
         * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
         */
        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                public void onCancel() {}
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(this.facebook);
        asyncRunner.request("me", new meRequestListener());
    }
}
```

That is my code to connect with FB to log in. I've two doubts with it:
1. How do I get the user info? (FB name)
2. How do I store it in the database. The problem here is that even if I allow an user to log in via facebook, there can be other users with the same name. So, does fb allow me to get their e-mail address for creating an unique entry in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want unique identifier for user, use his facebook id. To get this - you can use graph API that is provided by FB. More info about this here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
To get basic info (with facebook id) of currently logged user, you can use this api: https://graph.facebook.com/me (it works only, if user has valid access token.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install an extension, similar to the core Android SDK, but no, here is what you need to do:

1.) go to github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

2.) download the facebook directory ONLY! The other directories are only examples.

3.) Put the files from the src (you can copy the drawables too, if you want to) in the package, you are currently working with

4.) You are good to go, you can use the facebook "SDK"

see also this example https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook download it , it is working example provided by facebook